# How to find jar dependencies when running Apache Pig script?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I am having some difficulties running a simple pig script to import data into HBase using HBaseStorage

The error I have encountered is given by:

```
Caused by: <file demo.pig, line 14, column 0> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[rdf:predicate rdf:object]'              

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setCacheBlocks(Z)V        
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage.initScan(HBaseStorage.java:427)

        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage.<init>(HBaseStorage.java:368)

        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage.<init>(HBaseStorage.java:239) 13_21.51.28.tar.gz
        ... 29 more
```

According to other questions and threads, the main response/answer to this issue would be to register the appropriate jars required for the HBaseStorage references. What I am stumped by is how am I supposed to identify the required JAR given the appropriate Pig function.

I even tried to open the various jar files under the hbase and pig folders to ensure the appropriate classes are registered in the pig script.

For example, since `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` was caused by `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setCacheBlocks(Z)V`

I imported specifically the jar that contains `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan`, to no avail.

Pig's documentation does not provide any obvious links and help that I can refer to.

I am using Hadoop 2.7.0, HBase 1.0.1.1., Pig 0.15.0.

If you need any other clarification, feel free to ask me again. Would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this issue.

Also, is it better to install Hadoop and the relevant softwares from scratch, or is it better to directly get one of the Hadoop bundles available?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I meet the same problem after upgrade hbase from 0.98.3 to 1.0.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

There is something wrong with the released jar: hbase-client-1.0.1.1.jar

you can test it with this code, the error will show up:

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setCacheBlocks(true);
```

I've tried other set functions, like setCaching, it throws the same error. While I checked the source code, those functions exist. Maybe just compile hbase-client-1.0.1.1.jar manually, I'm still looking for better solution...

============

Update for above, found the root cause is hbase-client-1.0.1.1.jar incompatibility with older versions.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-10841

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-10460

There is a change of return value for set functions, jars compiled with old version won't work with current.

For your question, you can modify the pig script $PIG_HOME/bin/pig, set debug=true, then it will just print running info.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register required jars.
Most important jars habse,zookeeper and guava
I solved the similar kind of issue by registering zookeeper jar in my pigscript